# Chat client how to forbid username from being used a second time?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, methods, wait

When the username is entered and the connect button is pressed:

```
public connect{...
sock = new Socket("77.70.65.222", 5000);
InputStreamReader streamreader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
reader = new BufferedReader(streamreader);
writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
Thread IncomingReader = new Thread(new IncomingReader());
IncomingReader.start();
writer.println("``connecto"); 
//sends message to server, which sends back a message ,which when read by my 
//IncomingReader class(implements Runnable) prints online users in "onlineUsersArea"
writer.flush();
String[] a = onlineUsersArea.getText().split("\n");
for(String s:a){if(s.equals(username)) throw new Exception();}
//throws an exception if the selected username exists
writer.println(username + "`has connected.`Connect"); // Displays to everyone that user connected.
writer.flush(); // flushes the buffer
...}
```

The problem is that the method doesn't wait for the `IncomingReader` to print the online users and because of that `a[]` contains nothing before the method finishes.
What can I do to make it wait for the `IncomingReader` and then continue from `writer.flush();`
If I add a `IncomingReader.join();`, after I press the connect Button, the client stops responding.
If there is another way for me to prevent a user from using a username that's already been used I'll be extremely happy to hear it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You really should format your code if you want others to read through it.

Comment: Just add `IncomingReader.join();` after `start();`.

Comment: The code doesn't seem to be complete and it's like super hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an attempt, but what if you run the writer on an other thread?
I think the problem is maybe that the main thread is blocked while waiting for the other thread to finish job.

(Hint: I wouldn't use throwing simple `Exception`-s if I were you. Define a new `Exception` type and handle just that type if needed.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I moved the code under writer.flush(); into the IncomingReader class and it seems to work exactly as I wanted it.